# Highcharts bubbles incorrect initial size, changes on resize

Tags: highcharts, resize, bubble-chart

[Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xz217dpb/5/). Click the button and see the change. The `chart.setSize(null,null)` causes the bubbles to resize, even though the chart's size hasn't changed.

*(Note that this is the equivalent to resizing the chart to a different size and setting it back again (I originally detected the issue by restoring maximized window then maximizing again).)*

I believe the bubble sizes after the resize are actually the 'correct' size; my actual use of the bubble chart updates the values using `point.update()`, which is where I noticed the change, even when figures weren't actually changing. So it would seem the initial render is incorrect?

Answer (score 0):

**Update**

Use [this workaround](http://jsfiddle.net/xz217dpb/15/) instead.

The previous workaround caused errors - using null arguments to `setSize` isn't supported, but happened to give the desired result. After a discussion on [Highcharts forums](http://forum.highcharts.com/post113599.html) I now have the following workaround. Note that one has to rebind to window resize after setting to a fixed size.

**Original**

As done in the OP [JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/xz217dpb/5/), using `setSize()` immediately after adding the chart will cause the resize of the bubbles to occur, setting them to their correct size.

```
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
chart.setSize(null, null, { duration: 0});
```

This appears to be a bug which I have [raised on the Highcharts forums](http://forum.highcharts.com/post113599.html).

[Edit: setting animation duration to 0, to prevent the change in bubble size being visible as animation takes place]